# Error 403 on simple request with CURL / PHP

Tags: php, curl

this is my code, is a simple request using cURL:

```
<?php
$ch     =   curl_init();
$url    =   "http://pt.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-random-br-br.php";
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL        =>      $url
));

echo curl_exec($ch);
```

When you run it, the following error appears:

```
Forbidden

You do not have permission to access / gen-random-en-br.php on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at Port 80 pt.fakenamegenerator.com
1
```

How do I solve my problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that could be bacause you actually cannot access this `url`. Try different `url` - it gives you same response?

Also try to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);` in your request.

Comment: In another url the error does not appear. 
I modified my code and the result is '1' => http://pastebin.com/h79q3pAd